# Trying to create a second header on my gridview, but get an error about the tables row sections

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to add a secondary header on my gridview that would appear just below the normal header text assigned in the columns on the asp page. I am trying to create this row using vb, but every method I find ends with the same error:

"The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer."

I have no idea what this means and the table works fine when I remove the code attempting to create another header.

Here is my normal code with a working table:

ASP:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="divGrid">
        <asp:GridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="small" ShowFooter="true" Width="100%" OnRowCreated="ASPxGridView1_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                There are actually fields here in my version
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small"></HeaderStyle>
            <RowStyle CssClass="dtMid" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

VB:

```
  Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView1.PreRender
        If (ASPxGridView1.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            ASPxGridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = True
            ASPxGridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
            ASPxGridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter
        End If
    End Sub
Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowIndex = 0 Then
        e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems like the error only occurs when I have a prerender Sub in there:

```
    Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView1.PreRender
    If (ASPxGridView1.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        ASPxGridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = True
        ASPxGridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        ASPxGridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView add second and third header row in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906327/gridview-add-second-and-third-header-row-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @VDWWD It is not a duplicate because I keep getting an error when trying to do it like the post you linked and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can change row type to be header using below code

```
Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowIndex = 0 Then
        e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18327885/3134112) for more customization

Comment: Whenever I try something like this I get this error: "The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer."